# Auto-selected "Reason for signing" in Docusign signing process

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to auto-select the signing reason in the dropdown so that the signer didn't have to choose one (we only have reason "I approve" available anyway)?

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing this modal and its drop-down? It looks like a template or API integration that you should be able to change. This is not a default DocuSign signing page, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the Signing reasoning through the Resource file. Refer to this page for more information: https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/CFR-Part-11-Remove-the-Signing-Reason-Parameter-from-the-Signature-tab?language=en_US

If you need further help, please open the support case (https://support.docusign.com/s/?language=en_US)

Comment: Also, make sure you check with your CFR Part 11 Compliance team before making such a change.